# Error while loading native library in Android Application

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, loadlibrary

I'm having some troubles about using a shared library (.so) in an Android application.
I have 3 projects:

1. Native code project => build c++ files in .so library
   Let's call it **libNative.so**
2. Android library project => calls the native code. The output of this project is a .jar file.
   Let's call it "**stack.jar**"
3. Android application sample which uses the android library project.

In the sample application (3) libraries' properties tab, I configured the stack.jar file to be linked with the .so library. My .so native library is well included in the generated APK.
=> Eclipse copies it in the "**lib**/armeabi" folder.

If I launch the APK on a phone, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libNative:
findLibrary returned null at
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365) at
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
```

I'm guessing the error is that Eclipse copies the .so library in a lib folder instead of **libs** , and that System.loadLibrary is looking for the path **libs/armeabi**..., right ? Or I may be totally wrong !

Thanks a lot for your help,

**EDIT**: when I install the APK, the .so lib is well copied in **data/data/mypackage/lib** folder. Still, I can't load it. Is it because the load is happening in the .jar file and not directly in the application sample ??

Comment: you try with ndk tools

Comment: Paste your code to include to load library. BTW library should be in libs folder.

Comment: Just doing a simple:  static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("libNative");
    }

private static native String myMethod(int p1, int p2);
In my project, my libs (.so and .jar) are already in the libs folder.

Comment: To load "libfoo.so", you want to `loadLibrary("foo")`.  So it sounds like you need to change "libNative" to "Native".  Also, if the actual `dlopen()` call fails, you'll see an error above the exception in the logcat output.

Comment: Also take a look at the contents of the generated archive.  This should be in the bin subdirectory.  Type "aapt list <apkname>".  This is what is getting uploaded to your device.  You should see your .so in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According you have generated a dynamic library called **libExample.so**

1. Put the libExample.so in the **libs/armeabi** folder of your project
   (create it if it doesn't exist)
2. Write in a class the following code as fadden said:

   ```
   try
   {
       System.loadLibrary("Example");
   }
   catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError use)
   {
       Log.e("JNI", "WARNING: Could not load native library");
   }
   ```

   Should work !

Comment: HI, is there any way to call this in in # 2) Android library project ? any Method ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want. Include dynamic library in Android library project ? JNI ?